# Does the windows scheduler skip threads that are in a waitable state? (waitable timer)

Tags: multithreading, winapi, timer, process

Pretty much as the title say. If a thread, or process is using a waitable timer and is in a waitable state, set with

```
DWORD WINAPI WaitForSingleObject(
  _In_  HANDLE hHandle,
  _In_  DWORD dwMilliseconds
);
```

does the scheduler  treat it in a different way to if it were doingwork()? i.e if the scheduler sets aside a time slot of (for example) 10ms for a thread but then when it looks at the thread and realises it is in a waitable state does the scheduler immediately switches back allowing the next task to start its time slot early; or does it just sit there and burn cpu time for those 10ms as if sleep() was being used? I've tried searching to find out how this is approached but can't find anything.

Comment: Sure, the scheduler pays no attention to waiting threads.

Comment: Did it occur to you to try it?  Start, say, 32 threads and have them all wait on a synchro object.  Then check with Task manager to see what the CPU use is.  It will be 0.

Comment: I could but that is why SO is here to save time and gain information from people willing to help. If I had all the time in the world I would just run experiments all day but I don't so I experiment with some items and ask questions about other items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waiting threads don't get executed. If you think about it, there is nothing to execute - the thread is waiting, so it wouldn't have anything to do with the CPU time if it was allocated.

I think your confusion might come because **you think that it's the thread that does the actual check** whether the object is ready. So the way you imagine it, I assume, is that `WaitForSingleObject()` is a function that is polling continuously, and is running in the context of your thread, and the scheduler allocates time to the thread so the thread itself can poll the object whether it is ready.

**This is not so** - it is the kernel that is checking on those objects, and the thread is in essence suspended. Once the object is ready, the scheduler will "activate" the thread and schedule it for execution.

Comment: The kernel doesn't even need to do any checking.  It's the syscall that signals the event object that makes the waiting thread ready, and likely running, 'immediately'.